# how with the filter css property pop-up in this element to leave the background white?

Tags: css

how with the filter css property pop-up in this element to leave the background white?
need to leave the inner white when fillter  ,   and I don't know how

now

[image]

need

[image]

```css
.first{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  background: white;
  
  
}

.first span{
    display: none;
  background: white;

  }

.first:hover{
    filter: brightness(55%);
 
  }
  
  .first span:hover{
      width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid;
      display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="first"> <span>alert</span></div>
<div class="first"><span>alert</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this style

```css
.first{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  background: white;
}
.first span{
    display: none;
    background: white;
  }

.first:hover{
    background: #0000004f;
  }
.first:hover span{
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: solid;
    display: block;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use filter, all children of that element will inherit it.

To achieve what you want you need to make it a sibling. Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
<div class="block-filter"></div>
<span class="block-message">alert</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
.block-filter {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid;
    background: white;
}

.block-message {
    display: none;
    background: white;
}

.block-filter:hover {
    filter: brightness(55%);
}
.block-filter:hover + span {
    filter: unset;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: solid;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: white;
}
```

https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/vYBJoeP

Comment: as an option, yes, but this is just an example, I have a table and I have a hover on tr, and block-message is td, I can not change (

Comment: In this case I suggest you use background-color instead of filter.